# Spring jpa save

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am doing the following logic in my code

1. Read an object using my finder
2. Call spring jpa save passing in this object
3. Read the same object again using the same finder 
   Between step 1 and step 2, I make no changes to the object. I do have a Cacheable attribute set on my finder method and I also have a cache eviction set in my save.

What I notice is that in step3 the call goes to the dB again while I expected that the data will be fetched from cache.

Will spring jpa cause a save (dB write) even if no value changed in the object?

Comment: You can easily check that yourself by enabling SQL logging

Comment: thanks @JensSchauder. I turned on sql logging and noticed that the save did happen. So does this mean that I have to check if anything got changed in the object before invoking the save?

Comment: If you loaded the entity within the same transaction you don't have to call save at all.  JPA tracks changes to managed instances and persists those at the end of a transaction without an explicit call to save or any other method.

Comment: thank you @JensSchauder